# Compiling C code for ODE Model into .so file for R package

Tags: c, r

I am organizing some R code I have written into a package.  This code contains MCMC algorithms for inference on parameters in ordinary differential equation models, so I will be solving the ODE thousands of times. Thus it is necessary to pass the model into the `ode` function of the `deSolve` package using compiled code instead of an R function.  Normally, I use the commands

```
system('R CMD SHLIB mymodel.c')
dyn.load(mymodel)
```

to use the compiled versions. Instead, I would like R to automatically generate the .so files when I install the package.  I cannot find a way to do this because these C functions are not for use as an R function.  I just need the path to the valid DLL to pass into the `ode` function.  It doesn't seem to make sense to make a wrapper for the ODE model since I can't use the function inside of R, but maybe I am confused.  I cannot find a package on CRAN that uses C code in this manner, so maybe it is not possible.

Comment: I cannot understand that what do you mean about the manner in "uses C code in this manner". For example, what cannot be found in "RSQLite"?

Comment: @wush978 I can see how that was vague.  I mean that I call the `ode` function and pass the name of a DLL as an argument, but the C code has no functionality within R.  It must be written in a specific format called for in the `deSolve` manual for use by the ODE solvers used in that package. I did not look at the RSQLite package yet, so I don't know if that packages has a similar use of DLL files.

Comment: Maybe you could put these .c files into `src` directory of the package. With proper setting of `src/Makevars` and `NAMESPACE`, R will compile the `.c` code in `src` to `PackageName.so` and load it when you execute `library(PackageName)`.

You could read the details in <http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html>

Hope that helps

Comment: @wush978 Thanks wush978.  I misunderstood what was going on with the useDynLib directive in the NAMESPACE file, but after including `useDynLib(odemcmc)` my C functions became available for use in the `ode` function.